# Passing a parameter in Raw SQL Ormlite

Tags: android, sql, parameter-passing, ormlite

I have this SQL.

```
select sum(distance) AS distance FROM RoadTravelTableFile where checkBoxBusiness ='1' and plate_Number = 'AAA567'"
```

I have seen this simple query for raw sql in the Ormlite document.

```
long maxUnits = orderDao.queryRawValue("select max(units) from orders");
```

With that example, I coded my sql like this and it works.

```
distance = (int) getHelper().getRoadTravelTableFileIntegerDao().queryRawValue("SELECT SUM(distance) FROM RoadTravelTableFile where checkBoxBusiness = '1' and plate_Number ='AAA567' ");
```

But I have a problem, How can you make the checkBoxBusiness and plate_Number value as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace current values with `?` and add arguments to the queryRawValue method.

```
Integer checkBoxBusiness = 1;
String plateNumber = "AAA567";
distance = (int) getHelper()
        .getRoadTravelTableFileIntegerDao()
        .queryRawValue("SELECT SUM(distance) FROM RoadTravelTableFile where checkBoxBusiness = ? and plate_Number = ?", checkBoxBusiness, plateNumber);
```

Comment: This works! But I have read about sql injection.. Is this safe? @WojciechKo

Comment: I guess it's not safe at all.

Comment: Normally parameterisation ("using ?") is considered safer as you are telling the database/driver that the contents of the ? is strictly a literal value, not a command/expression.

Comment: @nsandersen thanks for comment! After 4 years, now I understand what sql injection means and I can tell it seems to be invulnerable to sql injection.