# SQLException for getting date between two date strings in ORMLite queryRaw method

Tags: java, android, date, ormlite

I am a beginner in android ORMLite, I have a query which selects particular data from two tables using its model class based on conditions that its "date" field value should be between the given string dates.Below is my query.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try{
    int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String startDate="",endDate="";
    startDate=1+"/"+month+"/"+year;
    endDate =31+"/"+month+"/"+year; 
    String[] resultArray;
    if(parid==4){
        GenericRawResults<String[]> valueResult=dbHelper.getTransDetDao().queryRaw(
            "SELECT T.amount FROM TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H "
            + "WHERE H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id=" + id
            + " AND H.date BETWEEN " + startDate + " AND " + endDate);
        List<String[]> results = valueResult.getResults();
    }
}catch(Exception es){
    es.printStackTrace();
}
```

But its results SQLException as below.

```
07-29 11:38:10.653: I/Database(627): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "Jul": syntax error
07-29 11:38:10.653: W/System.err(627): java.sql.SQLException: Could not perform raw query for select T.amount from TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H where H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id==109 AND H.date BETWEEN Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015 AND Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
07-29 11:38:10.673: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
07-29 11:38:10.673: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryRaw(BaseDaoImpl.java:542)
07-29 11:38:10.683: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.db.SaveMoneyController.getMonthTotal(SaveMoneyController.java:232)
07-29 11:38:10.683: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.db.SaveMoneyController.getListData(SaveMoneyController.java:199)
07-29 11:38:10.703: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.view.MainActivity.loadExpense(MainActivity.java:398)
07-29 11:38:10.703: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.view.MainActivity.listClicked(MainActivity.java:316)
07-29 11:38:10.713: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.view.MainActivity.access$10(MainActivity.java:259)
07-29 11:38:10.713: W/System.err(627):  at com.example.fort.view.MainActivity$8.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:227)
07-29 11:38:10.733: W/System.err(627):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-29 11:38:10.733: W/System.err(627):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-29 11:38:10.743: W/System.err(627):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-29 11:38:10.753: W/System.err(627):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-29 11:38:10.753: W/System.err(627):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 11:38:10.763: W/System.err(627):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 11:38:10.783: W/System.err(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-29 11:38:10.783: W/System.err(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 11:38:10.783: W/System.err(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 11:38:10.783: W/System.err(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-29 11:38:10.783: W/System.err(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-29 11:38:10.803: W/System.err(627):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 11:38:10.803: W/System.err(627): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: select T.amount from TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H where H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id==109 AND H.date BETWEEN Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015 AND Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
07-29 11:38:10.833: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
07-29 11:38:10.833: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:184)
07-29 11:38:10.853: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:65)
07-29 11:38:10.853: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
07-29 11:38:10.872: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.RawResultsImpl.<init>(RawResultsImpl.java:28)
07-29 11:38:10.872: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryRaw(StatementExecutor.java:280)
07-29 11:38:10.885: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryRaw(BaseDaoImpl.java:540)
07-29 11:38:10.885: W/System.err(627):  ... 18 more
07-29 11:38:10.885: W/System.err(627): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Jul": syntax error: , while compiling: select T.amount from TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H where H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id==109 AND H.date BETWEEN Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015 AND Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
07-29 11:38:10.913: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-29 11:38:10.913: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
07-29 11:38:10.933: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
07-29 11:38:10.933: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
07-29 11:38:10.985: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
07-29 11:38:10.985: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-29 11:38:11.013: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
07-29 11:38:11.013: W/System.err(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
07-29 11:38:11.023: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.BasicApiCompatibility.rawQuery(BasicApiCompatibility.java:15)
07-29 11:38:11.034: W/System.err(627):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:180)
07-29 11:38:11.053: W/System.err(627):  ... 23 more
```

Below is the TransactionHeaders class.

TransactionHeaders.java:

```
public class TransactionHeaders implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "user_id")
    private Integer userID;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "description")
    private String description;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "date",dataType=DataType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    public TransactionHeaders() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TransactionHeaders(Integer id, Integer userID, String description,
            Date date) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Is it because of any string or date type mismatch? Somebody please help me to get out of here.

Comment: can you share the DB file ?

Comment: @RahulPatil sorry,It's not accessible for me

Comment: @RahulPatil this is one of the value for date in database table "Tue Jul 10 18:05:51 GMT+05:30 2015"

Comment: I think the date field value is stored as a string in database

Comment: you can copy your application  DB to sdcard programatically.  , and then copy from sdcard to desktop and share it.

Comment: @RahulPatil You don't need to copy it programatically. `adb pull /data/data/your.app.package/databases/yourdatabasename` is way enough.

Comment: @m0skit0 , As per my understanding adb pull data/data , works for rooted devices .

Comment: @RahulPatil If you're an Android developer, you should have (at least) one rooted device.

Comment: @m0skit0 , KJEjava48 mentioned that does not have rooted device, so I asked to do it progrmatically .  I work on frameworks , so I always work on rooted device , we execute sql commands by entering into shell mode , even pulling the db is not required.

Comment: @RahulPatil Can you state where he says he doesn't have a rooted device? I always pull the DB because I have better programs and specially saved queries to avoid wasting time ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 " sorry,It's not accessible for me" nd comment

Comment: @RahulPatil You've drawn your own conclusion from a comment that doesn't say the device is not rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: SQLiteException: near "Jul": syntax error: , while compiling: select T.amount from TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H where H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id==109 AND H.date BETWEEN Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015 AND Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015

This exception is trying to show you what is wrong.  The SQL query cannot be built as a string because it is expanding your date objects into their string forms.  Surrounding them with single quotes will fix the SQL issue but I don't think you will get results because of this answer:

> [SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

You are doing to need to try different formats of the dates using a date formatter.   See the [Sqlite date formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).  It may work if you change the date format to one of the supported forms such as:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

To pass in your date string, I'd use the SQL `?` arguments and pass the formatted dates to `queryRaw(...)` as arguments after the query-string.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the dates with single quotes (`'`):

```
"SELECT T.amount FROM TransactionDetails T,TransactionHeaders H "
            + "WHERE H.id=T.transaction_id AND T.account_id=" + id
            + " AND H.date BETWEEN '" + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "'"
```

I suggest you [to use SQL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736056/passing-a-parameter-in-raw-sql-ormlite) instead of concatenating to avoid this kind of errors.

Anyways, SQLite cannot compare string dates with time zones using `BETWEEN`. In Android I suggest you to store the UTC timestamp instead, which will definitely work with `BETWEEN` and also solve any time zone problem.